# Interface with method contains ValueTuple

Tags: c#, interface, async-await, tuples, task

I have got Interface:

```
public Interface Inter1
{
 ....
 Task<(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk)> GetBulk(int par1, int par2, string par3);
}
```

Then got some method:

```
 class MyClass{

   internal bool m_resultBulk;

 internal async void NewBulk()
 {
   ....
   (ITestBulk, m_resultBulk) = await service.GetBulk(1, 2, "ggg");
 } 
}
```

But `m_resultBulk` can't be found. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited your question title because `( TX, x, TY y )` is a `ValueTuple`, not a `Tuple` (which would be `Tuple<TX,TY>( x, y, )`.

Comment: `(ITestBulk, ` seems to be missing a variable for the first item of the tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```
 (ITestBulk, m_resultBulk) = await service.GetBulk(1, 2, "ggg");
```

the tuple on the left side is missing a variable name for the first tuple element. 
If you don't need the `ITestBulk` value you can use a discard like that:

```
(_, m_resultBulk) = await service.GetBulk(1, 2, "ggg");
```

If you need it, you need to declare a variable (because you cannot mix declaration and deconstruction in tuples):

```
ITestBulk testBulk;
(testBulk, m_resultBulk) = await service.GetBulk(1, 2, "ggg");
```

Answer (score 5):

(As a side note, your `NewBulk` method **should** return `Task` otherwise its callers cannot await its completion - it's important to avoid code that starts "fire and forget" async logic because it becomes impossible to safely clean-up after the async continuation completes (or correctly catch errors) - the only exception to this are event-handlers in WinForms and WPF - and that's because their synchronization contexts will correctly handle any failed continuations. 
 - Additionally, async methods should generally have names that end with the `...Async` suffix).

Anyway, your main problem is that your call-site for `GetBulk` (which should be named `GetBulkAsync`) is not correctly declaring the `ValueTuple` return local.

You want this instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    private bool lastNewBulkResult;

    internal async Task NewBulkAsync()
    {
        (ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk) = await this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" ); // Specify `ConfigureAwait` as appropriate too.

        this.lastNewBulkResult = resultBulk;
    }
}
```

However this code has problems: the continuation after `GetBulkAsync` could potentially run on any thread - which means your `MyClass`'s instance state (i.e. its fields) are being mutated in a **thread-unsafe** manner. The solution to this is to redesign your classes to rely on immutable-state and representing changes in state through method parameters and return values (or async results) which avoids the problems of thread-safety entirely.

### Regarding mixing `ValueTuple` and `await`:

This statement:

```
(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk) = await this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" );
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Task<(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk)> task = this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" );
(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk) = await task;
```

And is also equivalent to this:

```
Task<(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk)> task = this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" );
(ITestBulk testBulk, bool resultBulk) tupleValue = await task;
ITestBulk testBulk = tupleValue.testBulk;
bool resultBulk = tupleValue.resultBulk;
```

Or this (using `var` for declaration-side type inference):

```
var task = this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" );
var tupleValue = await task;
ITestBulk testBulk = tupleValue.testBulk;
bool resultBulk = tupleValue.resultBulk;
```

Or this:

```
var tupleValue = await this.service.GetBulkAsync( 1, 2, "ggg" );
ITestBulk testBulk = tupleValue.testBulk;
bool resultBulk = tupleValue.resultBulk;
```